# unexpected output graph (moire pattern)

Tags: plotting

I want to create strips in order to simulate 
[moire pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

I tried in one-dimension first

```
g[x_] := Plus[Table[UnitBox[(x - i)], {i, 0, 50, 3}]]

Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 70}, ExclusionsStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: the output of the code]

The thing is, why there is a large gap between 6 and 20. They should be divided evenly between 0 - 50.

However, when I change the plot range from {x, 0, 70} to {x, 0, 50}, I can obtain the desired graph as below

[image: correct image]

Later, I tried to create moire pattern in 2 dimensional space.

```
f[x_, y_] := Total[Table[UnitBox[(x - i), y], {i, 0, 50, 5}]]

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 50}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

I get this:

[image: unexpected out put]

There are two unusual peaks in the graph. Also, the moire pattern is not rectangle, although they are similar to rectangle indeed.

Thank you !!

Comment: Try increasing `PlotPoints`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It works!!